# How to scrape data from election website with unusual table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data from an election website and can't figure out how to pull this data using BeautifulSoup.

Texas Election Results
https://results.texas-election.com/contestdetails?officeID=1001&officeName=PRESIDENT%2FVICE-PRESIDENT&officeType=FEDERAL%20OFFICES&from=race

**Code I've Tried**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tx_url = 'https://results.texas-election.com/contestdetails?officeID=1001&officeName=PRESIDENT%2FVICE-PRESIDENT&officeType=FEDERAL%20OFFICES&from=race'


import urllib.request
local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(tx_url)
```

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(tx_url)
```

> /home/server/pi/homes/woodilla/.conda/envs/baseDS_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py:357:
> UserWarning:
> "https://results.texas-election.com/contestdetails?officeID=1001&officeName=PRESIDENT%2FVICE-PRESIDENT&officeType=FEDERAL%20OFFICES&from=race"
> looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should
> probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind
> the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup. that document to
> Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup

Here is what the table looks like:

[image]

Comment: Page looks dynamic. Have you checked some content is not coming from additional xhr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the error you're getting means that you're using `BeautifulSoup` incorrectly.

You need to pass a response from a HTTP client to `BeautifulSoup` like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://results.texas-election.com/races"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

Second of all, you **don't** need `BeautifulSoup` to scrape that page. Everything comes back in `JSON`. For example:

```
import requests

url = "https://results.texas-election.com/static/data/election/44146/246/Federal.json"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for race in response["Races"]:
    print(f"Results for {race['N']}")
    for candidate in race["Candidates"]:
        print(f"{candidate['N']} - {candidate['P']}: Votes {candidate['V']} - {candidate['PE']}%")
    print(f"Total votes: {race['T']}")
    print("-" * 80)
```

Output:

```
RESIDENT/VICE-PRESIDENT
ROQUE "ROCKY" DE LA FUENTE GUERRA - REP: Votes 7563 - 0.37%
BOB ELY - REP: Votes 3582 - 0.18%
ZOLTAN G. ISTVAN - REP: Votes 1447 - 0.07%
MATTHEW JOHN MATERN - REP: Votes 3512 - 0.17%
DONALD J. TRUMP (I) - REP: Votes 1898664 - 94.13%
JOE WALSH - REP: Votes 14772 - 0.73%
BILL WELD - REP: Votes 15824 - 0.78%
UNCOMMITTED - REP: Votes 71803 - 3.56%
Total votes: 2017167
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
U. S.  SENATOR
VIRGIL BIERSCHWALE - REP: Votes 20494 - 1.06%
JOHN ANTHONY CASTRO - REP: Votes 86916 - 4.49%
JOHN CORNYN (I) - REP: Votes 1470669 - 76.04%
DWAYNE STOVALL - REP: Votes 231104 - 11.95%
MARK YANCEY - REP: Votes 124864 - 6.46%
Total votes: 1934047
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
U. S. REPRESENTATIVE DISTRICT 1
JOHNATHAN KYLE DAVIDSON - REP: Votes 9659 - 10.33%
LOUIE GOHMERT (I) - REP: Votes 83887 - 89.67%
Total votes: 93546
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
and so on ...
```

EDIT:

To get the data for that particular [URL](https://results.texas-election.com/contestdetails?officeID=1001&officeName=PRESIDENT%2FVICE-PRESIDENT&officeType=FEDERAL%20OFFICES&from=race) you mention, just use this:

Note: This is only a fraction of the data, as the `JSON` is huge. I added code for dumping the entire `JSON` so you can parse it the way you want.

```
import json

import requests

url = "https://results.texas-election.com/static/data/election/44144/108/County.json"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()


with open("county_results.json", "w") as output:
    json.dump(response, output, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

for v in response.values():
    for id_, race_data in v["Races"].items():
        print(race_data["C"])
```

Sample output:

```
{'4250': {'id': 4250, 'N': 'KEN WISE (I)', 'P': 'REP', 'V': 0, 'PE': 0.0, 'C': '#E30202', 'O': 1, 'EV': 0}, '6015': {'id': 6015, 'N': 'TAMIKA "TAMI" CRAFT', 'P': 'DEM', 'V': 0, 'PE': 0.0, 'C': '#007BBD', 'O': 2, 'EV': 0}}
{'2966': {'id': 2966, 'N': 'BRENDA MULLINIX (I)', 'P': 'REP', 'V': 0, 'PE': 0.0, 'C': '#E30202', 'O': 1, 'EV': 0}, '6224': {'id': 6224, 'N': 'JANET BUENING HEPPARD', 'P': 'DEM', 'V': 0, 'PE': 0.0, 'C': '#007BBD', 'O': 2, 'EV': 0}}
{'2967': {'id': 2967, 'N': 'MAGGIE JARAMILLO (I)', 'P': 'REP', 'V': 0, 'PE': 0.0, 'C': '#E30202', 'O': 1, 'EV': 0}, '3708': {'id': 3708, 'N': 'TAMEIKA CARTER', 'P': 'DEM', 'V': 0, 'PE': 0.0, 'C': '#007BBD', 'O': 2, 'EV': 0}}
and much, much more...
```

How did I find the `JSON`?

> I've inspected the network tab of the Developer Tool of my browser. :)

Comment: Thank you! This is great, but I am wanting to scrap the table I posted that has more of the data broken down. Is there are way to do that?

Comment: Which table (election) do you want to scrape exactly? Because there are plenty of those.

Comment: This specific one that has it by county, https://results.texas-election.com/contestdetails?officeID=1001&officeName=PRESIDENT%2FVICE-PRESIDENT&officeType=FEDERAL%20OFFICES&from=race So specifically the pres/vice pres by county.

Comment: Weird but I don't see anything there. Just an empty table.

Comment: Alright, I see the request. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question with a picture of the table. How did you find the json file?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a big help to get me started. Now to move it to a data frame and filter what I want. Thanks again!